# #include equivalent in C# to share static data between a C and a C# version of a program

Tags: c#, c++, c

I have a .h file that I `#include` in a C program and that contains a boatload of static data (something along the lines of: `unsigned char const table[bignumber]={.....};` For the curious, it is a catalog of star coordinates).

Now, I use this same file in a number of C and C++ apps that I have written over the years. Sometimes I have to add some `#define`s to customize it, but it is essentially the same, which is great because I can easily make 1 change in this file and update 3 or 4 apps.

Now I am writing a C# app, and I would like to reuse this same file. Is there any way I can do that?

UPDATE some days later...

There is apparently no way to do what I want in C# :-(

What I ended up doing is using one of my C program that includes the data to output a C# equivalent of the data...

The data is around 40KB of raw bytes... In C, this is compiled as const data in my code and takes 40Kb... There is no runtime cost in loading the data as it is loaded (as raw data again) when the program file is loaded.

On the embedded systems that I use, there is no cost at all as it is just there in flash, open for direct reading...
In C#, I ended up having to declare tables that are instanciated at startup, which will themselves be build out of objects instanciated at runtime (object[] var= new []{new object(...),....})...

The net result is that my code grew by nearly 500kb to include 40kb of data!!!! and I am guessing that there is non negligeable startup time cost invoved also... No wonder modern programs are so large and slow :-(

Thanks for the pointers..

Cyrille

Comment: Maybe use a T4 text template to translate it? C headers are not usually valid C# code.

Comment: Write a c program to surface it via a method that can be pinvoked from Net. Write a managed c++ program to surface is a a managed class to be used in Net. Use a tool with some search&replace capabilities to have something c# conforming from you h file.

Comment: Parse the file at runtime instead of building the data in at compile time.  Additional advantage: when you make one of those occasional changes, you don't even need to rebuild the program.

Comment: I'd convert the C header into a language agnostic format (xml, json, csv, or any format that suits you and that is easy to parse) and parse that file at run time during program startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your C header into a C# file and then use it. There are multiple tools you can choose from, for example this one: https://www.ispirer.com/application-conversion/c-c-to-cs-migration

Now, if you change your C file, you may want to automatically change your C# as well, which could be a step automatically performed during a deployment.

Or you can create a DLL and use that, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979 for example. You can rebuild and override the DLL as well.

It seems that it might be a good idea to have a DLL built so if there are multiple projects and applications using it, then they could include refreshing it into their building process.

Comment: _"Or you can create a DLL and use that"_ - please elaborate on how that's meant to work -  because (to my knowledge) the only way you can get "exports" from a C `.dll` is by using Win32 COM IDL (or WinMD) which is hideously complicated...

Comment: @Dai is this page helpful? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w

Comment: That article just describes normal C function exports - any C# program using `DllImport` to use those functions doesn't automatically get the C program's `#define` and other struct/constants/data available, they'll still have to be manually re-defined in C#.